# Comparing 2 ArrayLists and returning the common elements

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, collections

I am trying to compare two ArrayLists (i.e. ArrayList, list1  and ArrayList) testQueryValueand return the common elements between them. Below is what I have tried

```
private List<Loading> matchLists(List<Loading> list1 ,List<Test>  list2) {
        
    List<Loading> matchCriteria = new ArrayList<Loading>(list1);
    List<String>testQueryValue= list2.get(0).getTestQueryValues();
    for(Loading match: list1) {
    for(Sring test: testQueryValue){
        if (matchCriteria.contains(test)) {
            matchCriteria.add(test); // Error: The method add(Loading) in the type List<Loading> is not applicable for the arguments (String)
        }
    }
    return matchCriteria;
}
```

After editing this code as above  getting the error as in the commented line in the code.

I know this question has already been asked several times. Based on the answers I have tried this approach and am unable to return the match.
I am iterating through each elements of list1 which is a List of Loading, it contains nested arrays,and check if any element has test (subset of testQueryValue) in it? Then add test as the last element of matchCriteria which the method returns.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: "matchCriteria is returning null." - I don't see anything called `matchCriteria` that could return anything or that could be `null`. Do you mean the list is empty? ( Due to you using `contains(match)` it should never contain `null` directly).

Comment: Also, `MatchCriteria`, `getList2QueryValues()` etc. don't seem to be JDK classes, so what library are you using? You need to elaborate, add some example input and required output and ideally provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Thomas I have edited the code. The two lists are non empty i have debugged it and I see the values.  Sorry that MatchCriteria reference variable I used it further for setting some lombok values. I removed in the edit and about providing the example values. I am not supposed to share as it is my projects data.

Comment: Which of `List<String>` or `List<Loading>` does your method return?

Comment: @saka1029 it should return List<Loading> with matchCriteria= matcching testQueryValue

Comment: But the method declaration is not.

Comment: Apologies I edited it. @saka1029

Comment: Not considering efficiency using `testQueryValue.contains(...)` could be a way to solve it assuming that `testQueryValue` contains values you want your `Loading` instances to match. But since this is a `List<String>` you need to pass a string to `contains()` i.e. you need to extract the value you want to look for from `match`  and pass that to the method.

Comment: `list2` is declared as `List<Test>`.  But the element type is `Loading` in `for` loop.  Does the type `Test` implement or inherit `Loading`?

Comment: @saka1029 : My bad its list1 and not list2 in for loop. AS I changed the names from original i got confused. Apologies for that as well. Thanks for correcting. I have edited it yet again.

Comment: @Thomas exactly that's what I want to do. Compare testQueryValue contains values you want your Loading instances to match.
How to extract the value from match ?

Comment: Well, that's something I can't tell because I don't know what `Loading` looks like and what value you need. But that shouldn't be too hard to do, just build a method that returns or constructs the string you need.

Comment: @Thomas Match contains multiple data as nested arrays. Actually:

Comment: @Thomas Match contains multiple data as nested arrays. I have edited my code above. I want to get the matching testQueryValues and add it as a last element to the matchCriteria.

Comment: Well, ypu can't call `matchCriteria.add(test);` but would need to create a `Loading` instance out of `test` (how that works depends on the same things as I stated above). Assuming there's a `Loading(String)` constructor and good implementations of `equals()` and `hashCode()` you could do something like `Loading testLoading = new Loading(test); if( !matchCriteria.contains(testLoading) ) { matchCriteria.add(testLoading); }` - or better yet, use a `Set` (`LinkedHashSet` if you need to preserve order) since this would already handle duplicates, so no need for a `!contains()` check.

Comment: @Thomas could you please post this in answer. I want to accept this as answer. Your explanation helped me in great deal to resolve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, `matchCriteria.add(test)` isn't going to work for `List<Loading> matchCriteria` and `String test`.

Instead, you'd need to first create an instance of `Loading` using whatever `test` is. That would mean you'd need a constructor like `Loading(String data)` which is able to build a reasonable `Loading` instance.

In order to use `matchCriteria.contains(Loading)` the `Loading` class needs to have a reasonable implementation of `equals(Object)` and by contract `hashCode()` as well.

Finally, I assume you want to only add a `Loading` instance if it isn't already present in `matchCriteria`, i.e. you don't want duplicates. That would mean you'd be better off with a set, e.g. like this:

```
//LinkedHashSet keeps insert order
Set<Loading> matchCriteria = new LinkedHashSet<>(list1);

List<String>testQueryValue = list2.get(0).getTestQueryValues();
for(Loading match: list1) {
  for(Sring test: testQueryValue){
      matchCriteria.add(new Loading(test));
  }
}

return new ArrayList<>(matchCriteria);
```

If you want to keep using a list, your inner loop would probably need to look like this:

```
for(Sring test: testQueryValue){
  Loading testLoading = new Loading(test);
  if( !matchCriteria.contains(testLoading) ) {
    matchCriteria.add();
  }
}
```

Or, if you only want to create `Loading` instances if they are needed, use something like this:

```
Map<String, Loading> matches = new LinkedHashMap<>();
list1.forEach(loading -> matches.put(loading.getStringRepresentation, loading) );

for(Sring test: testQueryValue){
  matches.computeIfAbsent(test, key -> new Loading(key));
}

return new ArrayList<>(matches.values());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of `retainAll()` method

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String surName;
    private int age;
    
    public Person(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        
    }
    public Person(String name, String surName, int age) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.surName = surName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [name=" + name + ", surName=" + surName + ", age=" + age + "]";
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Person other = (Person) obj;
        return Objects.equals(name, other.name);
    }
    
    
    
}

public class PersonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Person> listofPerson = new ArrayList<>();
        listofPerson.add(new Person("Jane", "Brown", 18));
        listofPerson.add(new Person("John", "Smith", 20));
        listofPerson.add(new Person("Adam", "Williams", 18));
        
        List<Person> listofPerson2 = new ArrayList<>();
        listofPerson2.add(new Person("Jane", "Brown", 18));
        listofPerson2.add(new Person("John", "Smith", 20));
        listofPerson2.add(new Person("Adam", "Williams", 18));
        listofPerson2.add(new Person("Bravo", "Joan", 18));
        
        listofPerson2.retainAll(listofPerson);
        System.out.println(listofPerson2);

    }
}
```

Sample output

```
[Person [name=Jane, surName=Brown, age=18], Person [name=John, surName=Smith, age=20], Person [name=Adam, surName=Williams, age=18]]
```

Since I have overriden the equals method of parameter `name` It will retain all elements having same `name` in both the `lists`.

In your case, may be you can try the below method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Person> listofPerson = new ArrayList<>();
    listofPerson.add(new Person("Jane", "Brown", 18));
    listofPerson.add(new Person("John", "Smith", 20));
    listofPerson.add(new Person("Adam", "Williams", 18));

    List<String> listofPerson2 = new ArrayList<>();
    listofPerson2.add("Jane");
    listofPerson2.add("John");
    listofPerson2.add("Adam");
    listofPerson2.add("Bravo");
    Map<String, Person> personMap = listofPerson.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getName, Function.identity()));
    List<Person> finalList = listofPerson2.stream().filter(name -> personMap.containsKey(name))
            .map(name -> personMap.get(name)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(finalList.toString());
}
```

Comment: but I am comparing one Person List and one String List.

Comment: I have editted my answer, Hope it resolves your issue.

Comment: List of Person1
"Jane", "Brown", 18
"John", "Smith", 20
"Adam", "Williams", 18

List of Person2
Jane
Williams

I want the output to be:
"Jane", "Brown", 18, matchCriteria="Jane"

Comment: Sorry I did not get you.

Comment: Here the finalList will have the matching elements, use your logic to manipulate the output :)